# How to increase low end torque in motorcycle?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, carburetor, torque, power-loss

I have Honda CB Trigger 150cc 14BHP@8500 & 12.5NM@6500. Whenever I ride in higher altitudes (above 3000m), Its power decreases gradually.

Is there a way to increase the low end torque without doing major external modifications?

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution for this.

Comment: Lower the weight. Easiest to remove weight from the rider.

Comment: @cory only if the OP has weight to spare - he may not ....

Comment: Does your riding altitude vary greatly? i.e. is it from sealevel to 3000m or is it always 2000-3000m?

Comment: It's a known issue with Carburetor bikes. There isn't much you can do about it, AFAIK.

Comment: I am planning a ride to spiti valley in India where altitude vary from 200m to 4500m :)

Answer (score 2):

It is struggling in the thinner atmosphere as your height increases. You need to increase the amount of air going into the engine to have any chance or get a larger bike with more low end torque that won't notice the losses so much.

Edit to reply to comment about changing rear sprocket for a larger one. 
Yes, you can do this, but you limit the top end speed at the same time - this means that if you hit max engine  rpm going downhill before changing the sprocket then you will be running the engine at max rpm for longer after changing it and decreasing the engine life quite substantially.

Comment: do you think replacing the rear sprocket with the bigger one help?

Answer (score 1):

Though you have a small engine, and the difference will be minimal, but increasing intake manifold runner length will move torque curve lower in the RPM range. But this will affect peak torque figures, as well as engine revving character - it will not be as rev-happy.

Answer (score 1):

There's less air pressure the higher you go. By the time you get to 3000m, you have about 2/3 of what there is at sea level. It gets worse the higher you go. Bikes with carburetors tend to lose more power with altitude, since the fuel/air mixture generally goes rich when you get into high elevations. I suppose you could add a turbocharger to increase manifold density at high altitude, but that would be rather involved. The simplest fix is to simply buy a more powerful bike. For example, my current bike has 105 hp at sea level. At the higher mountain passes where I ride, it's down to about 65. That's still a lot more than my old bike that had 36 at sea level.

Answer (score 0):

There is less air at higher altitutes, so you need a less fuel to maintain the correct mixture. On a carbed bike you need a smaller main jet, which is not convenient if you mostly ride at lower altitudes. Partially operating the choke can help.

Answer (score -1):

If your cause of concern is the tight bends with steep slope for which you need to be slow and still have enough torque, then you can do this trick:

Pull the clutch, turn on ignition, rev up to an rpm that is a bit higher than max torque rpm, then release the clutch partially so that the rpm reduces to around the max torque value (you can raise the rpm and release the clutch a bit to get even more torque). This technique can give you surprisingly high climbing ability from a standstill, that only Enfields can boast of.

The engine is still at its high torque rpm, but the clutch slippage allows for the torque to be usable at low vehicle speeds.

This technique is to be used only in such limited cases, and not for climbing a long  road uphill at 5 km/h. Otherwise you damage your clutch.